# Kiss FFT seems to multiply data by the number of points that it transforms

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fft, kissfft

My limited understanding of the Fourier transform is that you should be able to toggle between the time and frequency domain without changing the original data. So, here is a summary of what I (think I) am doing:

1. Using `kiss_fft_next_fast_size(994)` to determine that I should use 1000.
2. Using `kiss_fft_alloc(...)` to create a **kiss_fft_cfg** with `nfft = 1000`.
3. Extending my input data from size 994 to 1000 by padding extra points as zero.
4. Passing **kiss_fft_cfg** to `kiss_fft(...)` along with my input and output arrays.
5. Using `kiss_fft_alloc(...)` to create an **inverse kiss_fft_cfg** with `nfft = 1000`.
6. Passing the **inverse kiss_fft_cfg** to `kiss_fft(...)` inputting the previous output array.
7. Expecting the original data back, but getting each datum exactly 1000 times bigger!

I have put a [full example here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/912ca15cac001f0bf63b18cb107c730b), and my 50-odd lines of code can be found **right at the end**. Although I can work around this by dividing each result by the value of `OPTIMAL_SIZE` (i.e. 1000) that fix makes me very uneasy without understanding why.

Please can you advise what simply stupid thing(s) I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's like integrals - we usually don't mention the constant.

Comment: It really depends on the implementation. Check the Kiss documentation about scaling. Usually, the division by n is part of the inverse FFT routine. Looks like they skipped this step in Kiss.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is to be expected: the inverse discreet Fourier transform (which can be implemented using the Fast Fourier Transform), requires a division by 1/N:

> The normalization factor multiplying the DFT and IDFT (here 1 and 1/N)
>   and the signs of the exponents are merely conventions, and differ in
>   some treatments. The only requirements of these conventions are that
>   the DFT and IDFT have opposite-sign exponents and that the product of
>   their normalization factors be 1/N.  A normalization of \sqrt{1/N} for both the DFT and IDFT makes the transforms unitary,
>   which has some theoretical advantages. But it is often more practical
>   in numerical computation to perform the scaling all at once as above
>   (and a unit scaling can be convenient in other ways).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dft

Comment: That's a relief! Thank you most kindly.